# In lexicographic order, do numbers (i.e., "50") or alphabets (e.g., "a") come first if both are used?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to understand lexicographic. My codes is:

```
inventory=["10", "50", "100", "150", "200"]

SearchItem=input("Enter item: ")

LB=0
UB=len(inventory)-1
Found=False

while Found==False and LB <= UB:
    Mid=(LB + UB)//2
    if inventory[Mid]==SearchItem:
        print("Item found in the position: ", Mid + 1)
        Found=True
    elif SearchItem>inventory[Mid]:
        LB= Mid + 1
    else:
        UB= Mid - 1

if Found==False:
    print("Item doesn't exist.")
```

It's a code I wrote in which inventory is an array of 5 elements. We then input a particular item and then search the item using the binary search technique.

I'm asking this because my list:

```
inventory=["a", "10", "50", "100", "200"]
```

outputs as:

```
Enter item: a
Item doesn't exist.
```

when the module is run.

I changed my list to:

```
inventory=["10", "50", "100", "200", "a"]
```

which outputs as:

```
Enter item: a
Item found in the position:  5
```

How come the latter one works but the other one doesn't?
I tried looking it up but the closest I got to find an answer was lexicographic order - but all of those are either only considering strings as alphabets in the list or strings as numerical values in the list.

Comment: in short, 'a' in ASCII / Unicode is 97, while '0' -'9' are 48-57.  Therefore value of 'a' is larger than number characters, hence 'a' comes later when sorting string

Comment: Just have a look at `sorted(inventory)`